# Android Kill AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have a Fragment with an AsyncTask running pretty much all the time.  When I change fragments, either opening a new one or pressing back I want to kill it.

What methods do I need to override to get this working. I tried a few but it didnt seem to have any effect.

Comment: There are examples and a lot of description [in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I did, to solve this problem was to set cancel on true and execute it afterwards again (when needed).

```
yourAsyncTask.cancel(true);
yourAsyncTask.execute( );
```

Comment: That `true` does not set cancel to true. It controls how it will cancel: `.cancel(false)` will set the cancelled flag which you can check inside your task via `.isCancelled()`. `.cancel(true)` will call `Thread#interrupt()` on top. Many blocking operations (e.g. `.sleep()`) can be stopped by doing so but some can't (e.g. when using a `Socket`).